# Debounce Rx.Observable & ignore values emitted in between

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactive-programming, rxjs5

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/90z9cy7j/2/)

```
  let sub = new Rx.Subject();
  let val = 0;
  Rx.Observable.fromEvent(window, 'scroll')
  .do(_ => val++)
  .debounceTime(500)
  .subscribe(c => sub.next(val)); 

  sub.subscribe(v => console.log(v));
```

I have an observable on scroll event. I would like to ignore the values from it unless some time has passed.

it would look like this (e being events, and the `debounceTime` being `500`):

```
 ---e1----e2----e3----e4----e6-----e7 <- events

 ---n1----------------------n6------- <- notifications

 0--100------------------600------ <- time
```

And like this:

```
 ---e1----e2----e3----e4----------------- <- events

 ---n1------------------------------------- <- notifications

 0--100--------------------500------------- <- time
```

Comment: Aren't you looking for [`throttle`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/throttle.md)?

Comment: @torazaburo yes, thank you, might wanna put it as answer. Here is a working fiddle with throttle https://jsfiddle.net/90z9cy7j/3/

Comment: It looks more like you're looking for `auditTime()` http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-auditTime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Debouncing and throttling are different](https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-throttling-and-debouncing/). You seem to want [throttle](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/throttle.md).

The fundamental difference is that whereas debouncing reduces *n* events to one, throttling lets through only one event per time window.

```
let val = 0;
const sub = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(window, 'scroll')
  .do(_ => val++)
  .throttle(500);

sub.subscribe(v => console.log(v));
```

However, this is not perfect. The user might scroll within a 500ms window in such a way that you would miss the last scroll. One [solution](http://www.cloudypoint.com/Tutorials/discussion/javascript-solved-rxjs-debounce-event-after-throttle/) involves combining throttling and debouncing. I'm not sure this is the best idea, though.

By the way, you do not need to subscribe to one observable only to push values from it onto another observable. Just subscribe to the first observable.